# .load Wordpress Posts Call to undefined function query_posts()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

index.php:

```
<div id="MainContainer">

<div id="Content">
lalalala content
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Select" id="Load_PrivacyPolicy">
</div>

<div id="Content2" style="display:none;"></div>
```

header.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
 $("#Load_PrivacyPolicy").on("click", function() {
    $("#Content").hide();
    $("#Content2").show( );
    $("#Content2").load( "http://www.prismasites.com/wp-content/themes/Prismasites/PricingDisclaimer.php");
 });
});
</script>
```

PricingDisclaimer.php

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>

<?php query_posts('p=1272' ); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
<?php
echo the_content();
endwhile; ?>
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function query_posts() in /srv/disk12/1806831/www/prismasites.com/wp-content/themes/Prismasites/PricingDisclaimer.php on line 5
```

I get this error because I try to use query_posts

How come it does not allow me to use query_posts?

Are you serious?

Are you telling me it's impossible to load Wordpress Posts into a .php file that is loaded into DIV file?

How can I load wordpress posts (query_posts) into a .php that is loaded into a DIV?

Comment: Are you trying to use a WordPress function without initiating WordPress?

Comment: I want to insert the wordpress post into the .php file and then load the .php file into a div in my index.php - I want to be able to edit the post on wordpress;.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the following line at the top of PricingDisclaimer.php (if you need to use WordPress functions, you need to include the header).

```
<?php require_once('../../../wp-blog-header.php'); ?>
```

Remove `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` this line from PricingDisclaimer.php.

Update your jQuery code to following,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Load_PrivacyPolicy").on("click", function() {
        $("#Content").hide();
        $("#Content2").show();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/wp-content/themes/Prismasites/PricingDisclaimer.php',
            method: 'get',
            datatype: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#Content2").html(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
                // Error handling
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Note: [This](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) is the right method to perform Ajax calls in WordPress.

Comment: '../../../wp-blog-header.php' 

What are the "..." dots supposed to mean? Do I include the dots exactly as is or do I put my website's directory?

Comment: Do I put this in <?php><?> tags or do I put it inside my <header></header> tags?

Comment: I copied your code exactly as it is and I pasted it at the top of my PricingDisclaimer.php - go to www.prismasites.com - scroll down to the "Pricing Plan" Section - Hit the first submit button - It no longer gives me an error but NOW it does NOT display any of the echo post content. I need it to display the echo post content. Why is it not displaying the echo post content?

Comment: I've added the script update to the answer, please try that.

Comment: If you are still getting the error, try to check the network and see if the request is sending to PricingDisclaimer.php.